# Is there any way to receive Whatsapp messages without exposing app to the Internet (webhooks)?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've been checking the documentation about WhatsApp Business API and Twilio Sandbox for Whatsapp and the only way I see to receive messages configuring URL for my application endpoints.

The thing is management and sec won't approve publishing an endpoint on our network to this matter. The acceptable way for them would be consuming messages from a client in the same way one connects to a mail server or any other service.

Is there any documented alternative to using endpoints to MY application?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at following an approach (which also applies to WhatsApp) mentioned in this blog.

[Handling High Volume Inbound SMS and Webhooks with Twilio Functions and Amazon SQS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/handling-high-volume-inbound-sms-and-webhooks-with-twilio-functions-and-amazon-sqs.html)

> This can also be handy if you don’t have a public webhook URL you can
> configure with Twilio, and would rather process these messages by
> polling SQS from the comfort of your own internal servers.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. Following your suggestion I had a conversation with a Twilio's engineer and will probably end keeping everything under Twilio's infra using Functions to define the endpoints + Sync for temporary storage between pollings.